# Gulp isn't running tasks in a series

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, gulp

I'm trying to write a function that will delete files in dist that no longer exist in src. When I run the task "clean" below with "gulp clean" on the command line, I only get "clean" as console output, and no files are created. This means that readSrcFiles, readDistFiles, and parseFiles aren't running for some reason. Why?

```
task("clean", function () {
        console.log("clean");
        task("default", series(readSrcFiles, readDistFiles, parseFiles));
        del(["temp"]);
        return Promise.resolve("cleaned");
    });

function readSrcFiles() {
    console.log("readSrc");
    return src("./src/**/*")
        .pipe(filelist("_filelist_src.json", { relative: true }))
        .pipe(dest("./temp"));
}

function readDistFiles() {
    console.log("readDist");
    return src("./name.github.io/**/*")
        .pipe(filelist("_filelist_dist.json", { relative: true }))
        .pipe(dest("./temp"));
}
function parseFiles() {
    console.log("parseFiles");
    let srcFiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./temp/_filelist_src.json"));
    let distFiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./temp/_filelist_dist.json"));
    distFiles.forEach((element) => {
        if (!srcFiles.includes(element)) {
            console.log(del.sync(["name.github.io/" + element]));
        }
    });
}
```

At first I didn't have this split up into functions, but then it would only run the src command that was being returned, which obviously didn't let me do anything afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, at least this problem.

```
task(
"default",
series(
    "html_imports",
    parallel(readSrcFiles, readDistFiles),
    parseFiles /* , "serve" */
)
);

function readSrcFiles(res) {
    console.log("src");
    return src("./src/**/*")
        .pipe(filelist("_filelist_src.json", { relative: true }))
        .pipe(dest("./temp"));
}

function readDistFiles(res) {
    console.log("dist");
    return src("./name.github.io/**/*")
        .pipe(filelist("_filelist_dist.json", { relative: true }))
        .pipe(dest("./temp"));
}
function parseFiles(res) {
    console.log("parse");
    let srcFiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./temp/_filelist_src.json"));
    let distFiles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./temp/_filelist_dist.json"));
    distFiles.forEach((element) => {
        if (!srcFiles.includes(element)) {
            console.log(del.sync(["name.github.io/" + element]));
        }
    });
    del.sync(["temp"]);
    return Promise.resolve("cleaned");
}
```